# How to git rebase a branch from another branch to master directly?

Tags: git, rebase

This is my current tree:

```
... O (master)
    | 
    +- O (feat-A branch) 
       | 
       +- O ... O (feat-B branch)
```

It seems that I can't rebase feat-B branch to master(to make it directly under master branch without Feat-A branch commits) for pull request to remote fork like this:

```
... O (master)
    | 
    +- O (feat-A branch) 
    | 
    +- O ... O (feat-B branch)
```

Feat-A branch and Feat-B branch has no overlapped changes of each other, so what command should I use to achieve to above result? I tried `git rebase master` on Feat-B branch but it does nothing. With Interactive rebase, I can't drop commits that belong to Feat-A branch.

Comment: What are the `O`s? what are the `+`s?

Comment: @kabanus `O` is actual commit, `+` is lines for illustration only.

Comment: tl;dr: `git rebase --onto master A B`

Comment: The dup is the answer, its good.

Comment: Please explain why you "can't drop commits that belong to Feat-A branch" using interactive rebase.

Comment: @r3musn0x `drop` keyword doesn't show as highlighted so I think it doesn't work.

Comment: @Roy, I don't think there is a drop keyword. To remove commits using interactive rebase just remove the corresponding lines from the list.